# Locking computer remotely

Tags: windows

Is there any way that one can lock a desktop computer remotely? For example, if one accidently leaves a computer logged on, would there be a way to lock that computer using Remote Connection (VPN)?

Comment: Are you trying to do this programatically?

Comment: No, not really. That's why I apologize for posting the question on SO. I am not sure where it belongs. I am just looking for a practical way of doing that.

Comment: This is much better suited for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) then.

Answer (score 12):

Use [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) to invoke:

```
rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation
```

on your remote PC.

If you are currently on PC_A and want to lock PC_B, type this on your command line (on PC_A):

```
psexec \\\PC_B -u user -p pass "rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation"
```

This way `rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation` will be invoked on PC_B.

Comment: where should this be invoked? On my local computer, or on the remote?

Comment: Yep that was it. Thanks yo

Comment: @Artur Doesn't work... PsExec could not start rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation on computername
:
The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: @JeanCarlosSuárezMarranzini: For some strange reason the remote command gives me that error unless I remove the quotes. And for completeness, if you are on a domain, you must indicate it, otherwise you'll get a "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.". So the command that works for me is `psexec \\PC_B -u Domain\user -p pass rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation`. In case it helps, I am sending the command from Windows 7 to Windows XP.

Comment: That's slick.  Can you remotely unlock it?

Answer (score 4):

You can create a file with an arbitrary name and the suffix bat use this  code  in bat file

```
rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation
```

save  and run

Answer (score 0):

You can use SysInternal tools, mainly the [PsShutdown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psshutdown) tool. You would get an instance of cmd on the PC and execute the lock command.

Example:

```
psshutdown \\computername -l
```

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to need some set-up beforehand. Is there any way of doing that as an emergency solution?

Comment: If your a domain admin you should be ok?

Comment: I know this might sound trivial, but when one uses VPN to connect remotely, would doing Start -> Lock on the remote session lock the remote computer?

Comment: VPN is used to connect to a network. Depending on the software used to connect would distinguish if its going to run it on a local or on a remote PC. Using Sysinternals if you have your network set up you should be ok

Comment: @Mariam: there may be many scenarios. You may be connected to VPN which means that you are 'kind of' part of some remote network (you are within that network). It does not mean you must be using remote desktop of any PC. Using VPN is not the same as using remote desktop. In general if you use remote desktop and disconnect - your PC will be locked (desktop). Example I showed you is when you physically work on a PC and walk away - desktop may be left 'open'/unlocked (unless configured to lock after timeout)

Comment: @Artur So using VPN, I should be able to just lock the computer using Start -> Lock?

Comment: @Mariam: First - your account on that PC must have a password. Second - if you are on remote desktop (via VPN or within local network) any person that may sit physically in front of this PC will see desktop locked. He/She may kick you off logging in. If you disconnect from remote desktop it is left locked. OF course you do not have to use remote desktop and may use RealVNC etc which bahaves differently - it would be long to describe everything

Comment: @Artur Thanks for bearing with me. Let's call the remote computer CompA, and the laptop used to remotely access the other computer CompB. So, CompA has a username and a password, but I might have accidently left without locking CompA. So I use VPN on CompB to access CompA. My question is: If, on the remote session, I click on Start -> Lock, would that lock CompA? In other words, if someone goes physically to check on CompA, will he now find it to be locked?

Comment: @Meriam: It is sufficient for you to log in there remotely and it will become locked for any person that might sit there physically.

Answer (score -1):

```
Option Explicit
Dim objWMIService, objProcess
Dim strShell, objProgram, strComputer, strExe, strInput
strExe = "rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation"
' Input Box to get name of machine to run the process
Do
strComputer = (InputBox(" ComputerName to Run Script",_
"Computer Name"))
If strComputer <> "" Then
strInput = True
End if
Loop until strInput = True

' Connect to WMI
set objWMIService = getobject("winmgmts://"_
& strComputer & "/root/cimv2")
' Obtain the Win32_Process class of object.
Set objProcess = objWMIService.Get("Win32_Process")
Set objProgram = objProcess.Methods_( _
"Create").InParameters.SpawnInstance_
objProgram.CommandLine = strExe

'Execute the program now at the command line.
Set strShell = objWMIService.ExecMethod( _
"Win32_Process", "Create", objProgram)

'WScript.echo "Created: " & strExe & " on " & strComputer
WSCript.Quit
' End of Example of a Process VBScript
```